# REST API returning empty response with 200 status code

Tags: rest

Below is my method from Controller class. If the service.getItems() return more than 70 items, then i am seeing empty response with 200 status code.
If the items returned are less in number i.e. 20 or 30, the response is as expected.
How to solve this issue?

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @GetMapping(value = "", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<ABCObject> getList(@RequestParam(required = false) String param, HttpServletRequest 
                               httpServletRequest) {

    return service.getItems();
}
'''
```

Comment: We need more information to help u with this. E.g. what tools are u using? How do you call your api?

Comment: Its a java application deployed on tomcat server. API is tested through Postman

Comment: How big is the response in bytes/kb/mb? Seems like postman has a 50 MB limit. You should also check if tomcat has a limit. I would not expect your java code to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

After putting few hours of debugging i was able to solve the issue. My app used spring-boot-2.2.4 version which internally uses jetty server-9.4.25.
This jetty server has a known bug and throughs JsonMappingException when the data is more.

This issue has been fixed in jetty server version 9.4.26.v20200117. After i upgraded the spring boot version to 2.2.5 (which includes jetty version 9.4.26.v20200117), the issue got resolved.